# Как правильно внедрить проект C++ в Android?

Tags: java, android, c++, visual-studio, android-ndk

Такая история, у меня есть проект написаный на C++, который компилируется и работает.

Так же у меня есть проект `android`.

По сути в проекте C++ всего несколько функций(маленький проект) и все они мне нужны в моем `android` проекте.

Теперь вопрос : как правильно сделать такую интеграцию?

Я думаю, что нужно этот C++ проект собрать как библиотеку, добавить его в андроид как билиотеку и работать с ним.

Или может добавить этот проект как дополнительный модуль и через NDK использовать его как то...

В общем никогда этого не делал. Подскажите кто с этим сталкивался как это должно работать? Какая последовательность добавления C++ проекта в `android` проект?

**Правка**

Я понял, что есть возможность добавить ndk в проект и следуя этому туториалу

https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code

добавить код "типо" C++, потому что код в JNI выглядит так

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_google_ar_core_examples_java_helloar_HelloArActivity_stringFromJNINew(
    JNIEnv *env,
    jobject /* this */) {
std::string hello = "Hello from C++";
return env->NewStringUTF(hello.c_str());
}
```

но это не синтаксис C++ ... По крайней мене насколько я знаю...

Это значит, что я не могу взять класс который написан на C++ скопировать его и пользоваться, так как синтаксис в моем C++ классе и синтаксис который предлагает `Android Studio` он похож, но это не одно и тоже. Значит мне нужно его переписывать...

Я подумал о второй опции... Ведь как то же должна быть возможность открыть проект в VisualStudio и собрать из этого проекта что то типа `.so` и уже эту библиотеку добавить как то так

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24357687/how-to-include-so-library-in-android-studio

Любые предположения приветствуются

Comment: Это вполне себе валидный синтаксис C++. JNI предоставляет С интерфейс и экспортируемые для java функции сооветственно тоже. В андроид студии сборка происходит посредством gradle плагина externalNativeBuild для cmake, который собирает .so.

Answer (score -3):

Смотри, вот документация от Google https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code

Comment: Лучше переписать основные моменты из ссылки в сам ответ, чтобы он не стал бесполезным, если ссылка перестанет работать. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer